# I have problem with accessing this array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have JSON https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/ and i need to put all data in table. 
How can i access the  "completed" ?
 I think that is bool. I need one button that print only TRUE and another one that print only FALSE. i tried something like this but doesn't work.

This is what i tried : PHP code

```
<?php } elseif (isset($_POST['onlyCompBtn'])) {?>
   <?php    $data = $_POST['onlyCompBtn']; ?>
   <br></br>
     <table class="table table-striped">
         <tr>
           <th>User ID:</th>
           <th>ID:</th>
           <th>Title:</th>
           <th>Compiled:</th>
         </tr>
    <?php foreach ($arrays as $key => $value)  {    ?>
      <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td></td>
        <td><?php echo $value -> completed['1'] ?></td>   // ['1'] or ['true']  doesn't work
      </tr>
     </table>
  <?php    }?>
<?php } ?>
```

I get this error : "Trying to access array offset on value of type bool"

Any suggestions? 
TIA!

Comment: Small tip: use `var_dump($data)` to check what variables you have and do they look how you need them to look. This really helps when things display different than you think they should (including not displaying at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gonna work :

```
 <?php foreach ($arrays as $key => $value) {    ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $value->userId ?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $value->id ?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $value->title ?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $value->completed ? 'Compiled' : 'Not Compiled' ?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php }   ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your json `completed` is just a boolean, not an array
(`{"userId": 1, "id": 1, "title": "delectus aut autem","completed": false }...`).

Change:

```
<td><?php echo $value -> completed['1'] ?></td>
```

To:

```
<td><?php echo ($value->completed ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE') ?></td>
```

**Udate**

If you want to filter the results you can place if conditions inside the foreach, let's say you want to show only the completed titles:

```
<?php foreach ($arrays as $key => $value)  { 
      if ($value->completed) {
         ?><tr>
           <td><?php echo $value->userId ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $value->id ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $value->title ?></td>
           <td><?php echo ($value->completed ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE') ?></td>
         </tr><?php
      }
   }
?></table>
```

In this case that you only show the completed ones it might not make sense to print it's completed column and it's value as it would be always 'TRUE' but I leave it just in case your filters are different.

Notice that the `</table>` should be placed outside the foreach.

Comment: <td><?php echo $value->completed ?></td> it print everything inside "completed". I already tried. I need to make one button that prints only True and another one that prints only False

Comment: look at your json, completed is just a boolean: `{"userId": 1, "id": 1, "title": "delectus aut autem","completed": false  }...`

Comment: you can change the 'TRUE' and 'FALSE' strings that I placed to show a button or whatever you need. If you can add an image, or html code of your expected output to your question we can give you a more personalized answer

Comment: Actually i need to do something like that but i don't know to do it. Im learning php and html css.

Comment: How can I print Titles that are Completed?

Comment: I've just updated the answer with a filtering example. You could apply different filters to the data depending on the value of some variables for example. You can change the if ($value->completed) for your current filtering condition

Answer (score 0):

Try decoding the data first with json_decode($arrays) after you've set the variable, I believe this is your problem